# make (a) good use of?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I came across a phrase like this:

> The board made firm promises that they will make a good use of his invention.

And I couldn't help thinking, is  ***a*** in *they will make a good use* even necessary? Does it make any difference if we remove it?

> The board made firm promises that they will make good use of his invention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they will make “a” good use for the invention then it would mean that the invention would typically be used for one specific use.

On the other hand. “They will make good use of the invention” could imply that the invention could be used for various different uses.

“a” here typically refers to one specific use.